# Convert two grayscale image to one 2 Channel Image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

i would like convert two grayscale images **[256,256,1] - [256,256,1]** to one 2 Channel Image **[256,256,2]**..

How can I do this? How can I conacte the two images to one?

Comment: `np.dstack(img1, img2)`

Comment: Whoops accidentally flagged the wrong duplicate.

Comment: do you use `numpy`, `cv2` or `PIL` ?

Comment: `np.dstack()` concatenates the colour (depth) channel. `np.hstack()` concatenates images horizontally side-by side. `np.vstack()` concatenates vertically one above the other.

Comment: if you use `PIL` then you can `merge()` grayscale images but `PIL` can create only  three channels image -  `RGB` - `Image.merge('RGB', [channel1, channel2, channel3])`

Comment: Ok, is there any possibility to Show the 2 Channel Image?

Comment: create empty channel to have 3 channels and create `RGB` Image - which you can show. OR you can try to add values in channels to create one channel (maybe similar to `(256*R + B)//(256*256)`) and then you can create grayscale image.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic principle is “matplotlib/opencv's image is actually numpy ndarray”, so you can use multiple methods supported by numpy.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

# Create grayscale image A (The shape as you describe)
greyA = np.random.randint(0, high=256, size=(256, 256, 1))
# Create grayscale image B (The shape as you describe)
greyB = np.random.randint(0, high=256, size=(256, 256, 1))

# Confirm the shape of the grayscale image A
print(greyA.shape)  # (256, 256, 1)
# Confirm the shape of the grayscale image B
print(greyB.shape)  # (256, 256, 1)

# Merged image
merge_image = np.concatenate((greyA, greyB), axis=2)
# Confirm the shape of the Merged image
print(merge_image.shape)  # (256, 256, 2)
```

---

Answer your questioning in the comments

Read [imshow()](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563)
If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is.
If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255].
If the image is 32-bit or 64-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

**Therefore, it is not supported to directly output an image with a color space of 2. You may use an average or weighted average to fuse the pixel arrays of the two images.**